# problem in CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding

Tags: iphone, web-services, encoding, core-foundation

I am getting data from webservice and displaying on in the label .
below is the code for that

```
cell.lblMainText.text=(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(
                                   kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                   (CFStringRef)cell.lblMainText.text,
                                   CFSTR(""), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

Here whenever the response from webservice is say: `%%%%%%%%%` then it dispaly null as the 
`CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` removes all `%` sign .So i am bit confused what to use in that place  which would return `%%%%%` as my string.

Comment: Are you using Monotouch?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. %% is not a valid encoding for the % sign. It would instead be %25 - see  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

This function will return NULL on failure, specifically if it finds an invalid percent escape sequence such as in your example.

For example, this works correctly

```
        CFStringRef string = CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("%25%25%25%25%25%25"), CFSTR(""), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

The server will need to return the correct encoding unless you want to get into parsing this particular string for this case yourself.